# Calling string in separate file in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, preg-match

I'm building a profanity/racial slur filter for my website. I have it working, but my `preg_match` string is quite long. I'm just wondering if there is some way to host this long string in a separate file in CodeIgniter and then call it when I need to in the `preg_match`.

I have googled this and I couldn't find anything, so I thought I would ask here.

What I'm doing now is hosting my string in the model and then calling this:

```
if(preg_match($filterRegex)){
  databaseStuffHere();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few options. Depending on how and where you are using this string and function, one may be better than the others.

**Config**

You could store the value as a [config](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html), in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['filter_regex'] = 'yourReallyLongString';
```

The primary config is auto-loaded by CodeIgniter, so you can use it like so:

```
$filterRegex = $this->config->item('filter_regex');
if(preg_match($filterRegex, $subject))
{
    databaseStuffHere();
}
```

**Constant**

If you're using this long string in several places and it would be useful to have global access, you could define it as as constant in `application/config/constants.php`. It will also prevent you from accidentally redefining the value.

```
define('FILTER_REGEX', 'yourReallyLongString');
```

Then use it with your function like this:

```
$filterRegex = FILTER_REGEX;
if(preg_match($filterRegex, $subject))
{
    databaseStuffHere();
}
```

**Helper**

Finally, you could use a [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html). You can load the helper when required, or auto-load it. You can create your own helper in `application/helpers/`. It could look something like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('filter_slurs'))
{
    function filter_slurs($subject = '')
    {
        $filter_regex = 'yourReallyLongString';
        if (preg_match($filter_regex, $subject))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }   
}
```

Having a function to handle this may make your code easier to follow and more meaningful, for example, in your controller, you could use it like this:

```
$this->load->helper('slur_filter_helper');  //assumes the helper file is: slur_filter_helper.php

if(filter_slurs($subject))
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up defining it as a constant since I am calling it somewhere else as well and it worked like a charm!

Comment: No worries, I'm pleased my answer helped!

Answer (score -2):

You can use it with  config file (system/application/config/config.php) to set configuration related variables.

====================== DEFINE WHAT YOU WANT in  config.php ===========================

```
$config['REQUIRED_SRTING'] = 'YOUR_REQUIRED_LONG_STRING_OR_WHAT_YOU_WANT_STORE';
```

But best place to set constant is

(system/application/config/constants.php) to store site preference constants.

===================DEFINE WHAT YOU WANT in constants.php=========================

```
define('CONSTANT_STRING','YOUR_REQUIRED_LONG_STRING_OR_WHAT_YOU_WANT_STORE');
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here? This question has already been answered so I am confused what you wanted to do with the config. The main question here was storing a long string not a path to a page.

Comment: I just want to clear that, there are two ways in codeigniter to for constant data, First one is  system/application/config/config.php file but best way are place is  system/application/config/constants.php, Here we can set constant directly

Comment: Your answer above is still not very clear because it is all in a code block I thought you were just giving a large block of code. The above answer actually outlines the three different ways you can declare a constant.

Comment: ok, Do you have some Idea about codeIgniter or programing?, In condeIgniter you can set constant in two places or two files. path about but the best place for constant set is constant.php not config.php. In constant.php you can set constant as In simple php coding. But in config you have to follow the codeigniter style constent settings.

Comment: Excuse me? I know quite a bit about codeigniter(I've been using it for three years now)and have a freaken bachelors degree in programing. We are arguing a mute point(and has been from the beginning)the question has already been answered and has been for eight months now. And my above comment was saying that the answer I marked as correct (and it is correct) states three different ways to accomplish what I was asking and is very well formatted and easy to read. The answer you posted was and still kind of hard to read. When you post an answer you want to explain what is happening in your code/